# Azure Function Exit code: 137 | Please review your requirements.txt

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I want to publish an Azure Function with the following command using the cli/Azure Core tools:

```
func azure functionapp publish myFunc
```

However I can not even publish the function as I always get an error when installing the requirements.txt

```bash
[15:29:01+0000]   Downloading torch-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (670.2 MB) | Exit code: 137 | Please review your requirements.txt | More information: https://aka.ms/troubleshoot-python
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.10.4 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
```

I saw that apparently this error is due to a lack of memory but I need all these packages.
This is my requirements.txt:

```
langchain
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-search-documents==11.4.0
azure-storage-blob
unstructured
unstructured[pdf]
unstructured[docx]
unstructured[pptx]
tiktoken
```

Essentially what I'm trying to build is a serverless Azure Function with a blob trigger that will automatically read files if there are changes in the blob storage and then chunk, embed and upload them to Azure AI Search. Therefore all these packages are necessary.
Is there any way to increase the memory limit or get around this issue?

I also tried this command but it did not make a difference:

```
func azure functionapp publish MyFunc --python --build remote
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issues when I tried to deploy the Python function to Azure Function App with the below packages:

```
azure-functions
langchain
azure-identity
azure-search-documents==11.4.0
azure-storage-blob
unstructured
unstructured[pdf]
unstructured[docx]
unstructured[pptx]
tiktoken
```

***Followed below steps to deploy the function to Azure successfully:***

- Create a new Function App with Premium Plan.
- Navigate to Function APp=> App Service Plan=>Scale UP, select the high pricing plan which offers more memory.

[image]

- I could deploy successfully.

[image]
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]